# Connect excel to azure datalake gen 2 with OAuth

Tags: excel, azure, oauth, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

When I am looking at [microsoft documentation of excels connections](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-query-data-sources-in-excel-versions-e9332067-8e49-46fc-97ff-f2e1bfa0cb16?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) possibilities and it says that my **Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise** can connect to **Azure Blob Storage** and **Azure Data Lake Storage**

I want to connect to my Datalake Gen 2 in excel, I'll go to the Data tab Get Data > From Azure > From Azure Blob Storage
[image]

***Here is the question***: How do I connect to my Gen 2 datalake with Azure AD / OAuth / username (user@domain.com) and password? Storage Account Key Access is disabled on this datalake. That includes Shared key and shared access signature (SAS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thank *KarthikBhyresh-MT* for his input that inspired me to find the right solution.

**The Solution**
First I found the url to the desired file inside the datalake inside azure portal
[image]

I copied the changed the url and changed the word **blob** to **dfs**

In excel (office 365) I Get Data > From Web, and put in the altered url. From there I get this image, where I can log into the datalake with OAuth credentials
[image]

Then I could load the simple.csv file into excel, work on it and see the transactions in the datalake logs.

Answer (score 0):

I can see only a UI connector for ADLS Gen1

[image]

### Alternately for ADLS Gen2....

Here is something I tried, you can use user **delegation SAS Key**, which is secured with **Azure AD credentials**.

1. Generate a user delegation SAS url for that blob you want to access.

[image]

2. Select Web Source to get Data,

[image]

3. If prompted, select **Anonymous**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shared access signature (SAS) is not an option as authorization with Shared Key is disabled for datalake gen 2 as mentioned above

Comment: yes, and that is why I have mentioned to use User Delegation key Option. There are two types of authorization, account access key for Shared Key authorization and  user delegation SAS is authorized with Azure AD even when AllowSharedKeyAccess property is set to false. Please try as shown in snip once